# Creating invoice design with the help of HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create an invoice design in a simple HTML table.
I tried my best but I unable to create that design in HTML.
I am a beginner in HTML and even read all chapters in w3school. But I don't know how I design this in HTML?
I tried the below code but it not as expected. What would be the code for the html tab design as I attached the image?

```html
<table style="height: 90px; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: solid;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 50%; height: 18px;">A</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 50%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 50%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 50%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 50%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 36px;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%; height: 18px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 12.5%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 12.5%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image as expected table in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pclDF.png)

Comment: You should use `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes to merge cells. With that, you will be able to make a single `<table>` and meet your expected table

Comment: Please help me, I tried the end from 1days but It does not happen to me..

Comment: Once you get your answer, you also need to consider what should happen if the invoice goes beyond one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible example using colspan and rowspan.

```css
/*to show cell's position*/

table,
td {
  border: solid 2px black;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.bold~tr td {
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
}

td {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

[colspan="4"][rowspan="2"] {
  height: 6em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="3">A</td>
    <td colspan="2">D</td>
    <td colspan="2">E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">F</td>
    <td colspan="2">G</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">H</td>
    <td colspan="2">I</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="2">B </td>
    <td colspan="2">J</td>
    <td colspan="2">K</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="2"> L </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SL</td>
    <td>Items</td>
    <td>Due DT</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Rate</td>
    <td>Per</td>
    <td>Dis%</td>
    <td>Amt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bold">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">AMT IN WORD</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E. & O.E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">COMPAGNY NAME</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

tutorials you can find via your search engine :

https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  table{
 height: 90px;
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  border-style: solid;
  
}
tr{height: 18px;}
.s1-l{height:120px}
.s1{width: 50%; height: 18px;}
.s2{width: 25%; height: 18px;}
.s3{width: 12.5%; height: 18px;}
.c1{border: 1px solid black}
</style>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tbody class="c1">
    <tr><th rowspan="3" colspan="4">A</th><th colspan="2">D</th><th colspan="2">E</th></tr>
    <tr><th  colspan="2">F</th><th colspan="2">G</th></td></tr>
    <tr><th colspan="2">H</th><th colspan="2">I</th></tr>
    <tr><th colspan="4" rowspan="2">B</th><th colspan="2">J</th><th colspan="2">K</th></tr>
    <tr><th colspan="4" rowspan="4">L</th></tr>
    <tr><th colspan="4" rowspan="3">C</th></tr>
  </tbody>
<ttbody>
  <tr><td >SL</td><td>Items</td><td>Due Dt</td><td>Qty</td><td>Rate</td><td>Per</td><td>Dis%</td><td>Amt</td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
<tbody>
   <tr><td colspan="3">AMT IN WORD</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>E.& 0.E</td></tr>

   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td colspan="4" rowspan="4"></td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="3">COMPANY NAME</td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here I re-did the code. With table you have to know the size of the table before hand. So this table was 24 by 8. Then you have to go row by row(tr) and then label them. Use the colspan and the rowspan to resize it base on what you want. tbody can be use to quickly style many cell in it.
Also I add in a style block to show you that you can use a class instead to quickly update a style to everything that has that class. I ended up not use your styles. Also the I use the th tag instead of the td because it has default style of center and bold.

Comment: Why should you use regular markup and flex when these datas deserve an HTML markup ? beside , to span rows & columns, grid would be required, not flex ;)

Comment: @levi please not vote me down... I don't know to use your answer.. Please help me to create the invoice design in html

Comment: @JustinParker Look back I redid the invoice and gave a explanation. UPVOTE ME PLZ

Comment: @G-Cyrillus You right using CSS on a table is actually a nightmare. I redid please take a look and upvote me if you want. First post btw.